# Injection of contenscript into a page not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I injected contentscript into a page by :

```
//this is in background.js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {"file": "contentscript.js"});
```

Then to check if it inserted well or not I modified an element on the page, but no changes made.
Did I inject it properly?

Here are my files :

**background.js:**

```
  //injecting contentscript here
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {"file": "contentscript.js"});

  //receiving end
        var title;
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
        if(message.method == 'setTitle')
        title = message.title;
        else if(message.method == 'getTitle')
        sendResponse(title);
    });
```

**contentscript.js:**

```
<script>

var table = document.getElementsByClassName("collapse")[0];

var marks = new Array();

 for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
   marks[i] = table.children[0].children[i+1].children[5].innerHTML;

 var total=0;
 for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
   total += Number(marks[i]);


//code to send the data to background.js
var fromDOM = total;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:'setTitle',title:fromDOM});

</script>
```

**popup.js:**

```
    var total= 0,percentage = 0;


    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:'getTitle'}, function(response){
   $('.total').text(response);
   percentage = total/7.25;   
   $('.percentage').text(percentage);

 });
```

Why is this not working? Any changes or errors?

**This is how my popup.html is looking :**

[image]

Comment: Start by removing those `<script>` tags from contentscript.js

Comment: I did it. Same result @rsanchez